# sending json web token using ajax to Node API

Tags: node.js, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to do an authorisation middleware using jsonwebtoken, cookie-parser to set cookies and jQuery in the client.

For that I'm using a middleware to check authorisations.

here is the middleware

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req,res,next)=> {
    try{
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split("=")[1];
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY)
        req.userData = decodedToken;
        next();

    } catch(error){
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
        })
    }   
}
```

In my API I'm creating and sending the token like this:

```
                const token = jwt.sign({
                        email: user[0].email,
                        userId: user[0]._id
                    },

                    process.env.JWT_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: "1h"
                    }
                )

                res.cookie('userToken', token)
                res.render('index', {
                    movies: {}, token:token
                });
```

In the client I'm sending back to the server like this:

```
var userToken = document.cookie;
        // console.log(userToken)

        $.ajax({
            url: "/movies/add",
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                console.log(xhr)
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + userToken);
            }
        });
```

The movies/add route is receiving the request, because it's printing 'it entered', but it's not redirecting to movies/addMovies. What am I missing?

```
    router.get('/add', checkAuth, function (req, res, next) {

        console.log('it entered')

        res.render('movies/addMovies', {
            movies: {}
        })


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the "page" via an AJAX call and returning the HTML (`res.render`) to the JavaScript.

If you're wanting to navigate to the other screen, you should either use a hyperlink or redirect using JavaScript (`location.href`).

Comment: where should I use the hyperlink or the redirect?

Comment: If you're trying to navigate to a new screen, you can replace the `$ajax...` code with `location.href = '/add'` (or whatever the actual URL should be)

Comment: but I want to navigate after sending a token to the server. Only after the server authorises

Comment: You'll want to authorize at the same time the request for `/add` is made, otherwise someone that knows about `/add` can visit the page without going through the process.  You could check the AJAX response for a 200, then navigate but that seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I've changed to this: ```$.ajax({
            url: "/movies/add",
            type: "GET",
            data:{
                'userToken':userToken
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log('sim')
                window.location.href = "/movies/add";
            }
        });``` and in the server ```const token = req.cookies.userToken
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY)```and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I've changed to this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/movies/add",
            type: "GET",
            data:{
                'userToken':userToken
            },
            success: function(){
                console.log('sim')
                window.location.href = "/movies/add";
            }
        });
```

and in the server

```
const token = req.cookies.userToken
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY)
```

and now it works